# What are good torrent clients that are compatible with ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility, bittorrent, client

Are there any good torrent clients that are compatible with ubuntu? Most of the main ones (BitTorrent, uTorrent) are only for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one included in any standard installation called Transmission.

I myself like Deluge.

In case you don't like transmission (just doesn't have the features I wanted is all, still works fine) and wanted to uninstall it (thepiratebay usually automatically launches your primary torrent client, only reason I uninstalled it) the terminal command is:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-gtk
```

I only say this because I had trouble myself finding the package transmission is under in Ubuntu at first.

Answer (score 0):

"Transmission" is a good and reliable choice for a Bittorrent client. I use it without any problem.